# Find Missing Sequence Values With GROUP BY Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the missing numbers for a sequence set that are categorized by years and departments. For instance, I have the following set of information in a table:

```
╔══════╤══════╤═════╗
║ YEAR │ DEPT │ NUM ║
╠══════╪══════╪═════╣
║ 2016 │ 1    │ 1   ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2016 │ 1    │ 2   ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2016 │ 1    │ 4   ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2016 │ 2    │ 10  ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2016 │ 2    │ 12  ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2016 │ 2    │ 13  ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2015 │ 3    │ 6   ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2015 │ 3    │ 8   ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2015 │ 3    │ 9   ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2015 │ 2    │ 24  ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2015 │ 2    │ 26  ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────╢
║ 2015 │ 2    │ 27  ║
╚══════╧══════╧═════╝
```

Normally I would `LEFT JOIN` onto a `TALLY` table, but I am wanting to retain what `YEAR` and `DEPT` the missing values are in. An approach such as below is what I would normally utilize, but it I'm not sure how I can loop back the year and department that the missing value corresponds to, especially since the `MIN` and `MAX` value can differ per`YEAR` and `DEPT`.

```
DECLARE @MIN INT = (SELECT MIN(NUM) FROM DOCUMENTS)
DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT MAX(NUM) FROM DOCUMENTS)

SELECT
    T.NUM AS 'MISSING'
FROM
    TALLY T
    LEFT JOIN DOCUMENTS D
        ON T.NUM = DOCUMENTS.NUM
WHERE
    D.NUM IS NULL
    AND D.NUM BETWEEN @MIN AND @MAX
```

My expected output would look like:

```
╔══════╤══════╤═════════════╗
║ YEAR │ DEPT │ MISSING_NUM ║
╠══════╪══════╪═════════════╣
║ 2016 │ 1    │ 3           ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────────────╢
║ 2016 │ 2    │ 11          ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────────────╢
║ 2015 │ 3    │ 7           ║
╟──────┼──────┼─────────────╢
║ 2015 │ 2    │ 25          ║
╚══════╧══════╧═════════════╝
```

I'm thinking I might need to create a `TALLY` table that contains `YEAR`, `DEPT`, and a `NUM` column for each of those, but that would be billions of values as I have years from 1800-2016 and 15 different departments with a `NUM` range from 1 to 100 million for some of those departments. So I'm not thinking that would be the most efficient/practical of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only one value that might be missing, you can do:

```
select t.year, t.dept, t.num + 1
from t
where t.num < (select max(t2.num) from t t2 where t2.year = t.year and t2.dept = t.dept) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.year = t.year and t2.dept = t.dept and
                        t.num + 1 = t2.num
                 );
```

In SQL Server 2012+, this can be simplified to:

```
select year, dept, num + 1 as num
from (select t.*, lead(num) over (partition by year, dept order by num) as next_num
      from t
     ) t
where next_num <> num + 1;  -- Note:  this handles the final num where `next_num` is `NULL`
```

This approach can actually be generalized to find *ranges* that are missing.  Assuming you are using SQL Server 2012+, then:

```
select year, dept, num + 1 as start_missing, next_num - 1 as end_missing
from (select t.*, lead(num) over (partition by year, dept order by num) as next_num
      from t
     ) t
where next_num <> num + 1;  -- Note:  this handles the final num where `next_num` is `NULL`
```

Comment: I am making headway utilizing the SQL 2012 approach, but there are cases where it won't be only one value missing. For instance, 74-77 may be missing. I see you touched on this in your third approach, but it appears `start_missing` and `end_missing` are not being utilized. How should I utilize this in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @PicoDeGallo . . . What do you mean they are not being used?  They are returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using a recursive cte, to generate all the numbers between the min and max num for a combination of year and dept. Thereafter, `left join` on the generated numbers to find the missing ones.

```
with t1 as (select yr,dept,max(num) maxnum, min(num) minnum 
            from t 
            group by yr,dept)
,x as (select yr, dept, minnum, maxnum from t1
       union all
       select yr, dept, minnum+1, maxnum 
       from x 
       where minnum < maxnum
       )
select x.yr,x.dept,x.minnum as missing_num 
from x  
left join t on t.yr=x.yr and t.dept=x.dept and t.num = x.minnum
where t.num is null 
order by 1,2,3
```

[**`Example with sample data`**](http://rextester.com/VOQZ26751)